# Python - Operations in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I have this dataframe which is read from an excel file:

I want to know the value of a given column, apply rules, then update it. I'm trying this:

```
ticker='BTCUSDT'
print(df.at[ticker,'Position'])

#Then, I want to update that value:

df.at[ticker,'Position']=1
```

When i do this, i get a **Key Error**. In this example: `KeyError: 'BTCUSDT'`

**Expected:**

```
print=0
cell after assign = 1
```

This works, however, if I first assign a value to the cell, in example:

if first i do this:

```
ticker='BTCUSDT'
df.at['BTCUSDT','Position']=0
#then this works:

ticker='BTCUSDT'
df.at[ticker,'Position']

df.at[ticker,'Position']=1
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide an example of DataFrame input and the matching expected output

Comment: As per your dataframe picture, you do not have a `BTCUSDT` ticker - rather you have `BTCBUSD`

Answer (score 1):

The following code will look for the ticker value `BTCUSDT` within the `Ticker` column, 
and change the value in the associated `Position` column to `1`.

#### Code:

```
ticker='BTCUSDT'
df.loc[df['Ticker'] == ticker, 'Position'] = 1
```

##### For example:

If you have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Ticker': ['BTCBUSD', 'ETHBUSD', 'LTCBUSD', 'SOLBUSD', 'FIMUSDT'],
                    'Position': [0,0,0,0,0],
                    'Quantity': [0,0,0,0,0],
                    'Price':[0,0,0,0,0]})
```

You can update the position value of `BTCBUSD` to `1` in the same way using:

```
ticker='BTCBUSD'
df.loc[df['Ticker'] == ticker, 'Position'] = 1
print(df)
```

#### Output:

[image: Updated dataframe]

Answer (score 0):

Ticker is not the Index but just a column. If you do `df = df.set_index('Ticker')` yoi should be good